# How to check whether a laptop has two hard drive bays?

Tags: laptop, ssd, drive-bay

I want to buy a new laptop. I have a SSD on my old Toshiba A300 which has two hard drive bays and I'm really happy with it. Now I want to have two bays on my new laptop, too, so I can use both HDD and SSD at once.

Is there a way to understand if the device has two bays? 
Maybe from the motherboard? I'm not sure if on each manufacturer website this kind of information is present but I think most of them are writing it.

Comment: Do you need an optical drive?

Comment: No, I need it for my current laptop because it can't boot from USB. So I'm using CDs only for OS installations. With booting via USB feature I will not need optical drive anymore. Here is my question about this situation: http://superuser.com/questions/611671/2-5-ssd-in-the-optical-drive-bay-what-about-the-performance

Answer (score 3):

If you can live without an optical drive in your new machine then you can get an [adapter to allow you to put a SATA drive in the optical bay](https://www.google.com/search?q=sata+optical+bay+hdd+adapter), replacing the optical drive there.

Comment: This is the alternative as you see on my other question. But this doesn't answer the question, so I can't accept it.

Comment: interesting, I have never seen these before.  Good to know they exist.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find if a laptop has to bays to put drives in is to simply, take the panels off the back/sides that would usually cover it to see if there is a second one, if not, then you only have 1.

Comment: When looking for a new laptop mostly online I can't do this... I mean understanding it based on product specifications which could be found on the manufacturers' sites.

Comment: Then the simplest way may just to email or call the manufacturer, unlike most companies these days, tower/desktop manufacturers usually have in house service with no wait time, so it wouldn't take long.

Answer (score 0):

Almost every manufacturer releases some sort of spec sheet for their hardware builds. In this case, Google is a great resource to find the specs you are looking for. Simply search for the make/model with "spec", or "hardware specification", etc as your operative key word. Good luck, I hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)