# 2.5" SSD in the optical drive bay - what about the performance?

Tags: laptop, ssd, optical-drive

I'm looking for a new laptop and I want one which has two hard drive bays for using both HDD and SSD. But I don't think most of the new models have two bays, so replacing optical drive seems as a good alternative.

I can't give concrete laptop model because I still couldn't choose one but in general is there some performance limitations compared to second hard drive bay?

As I know most of the new laptops use SATA interface for the optical drives but I'm not sure.

Comment: Replacing optical drives with SSDs is pretty common, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible to answer without knowing the specific model. In the worst case you could put the SSD in the primary bay and the platter drive in the optical bay.

Comment: Depending on the laptop, this may however not be the best tip. Many laptops have features that make harddrives in the primary bay more shock resistant. This protection is obviously nulled when you put a mechanical drive in the optical bay. So, depending on the model of your laptop, putting the SSD in the optical bay makes more sense.

Comment: I don't know specific model. But let's say if both hard drive and optical drive are on SATA (e.g. III) interface instead of mSATA etc.?

Comment: If they both use the same (speed) interface then other factors matter, such as what SBI said.